# Why do I keep getting an undefined error?

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

This is a search algorithm in python that navigates Romanian cities.

```
class GraphTree:

    graph = {
    'Oradea': set(['Zerind','Sibiu']),
    'Zerind': set(['Arad','Oradea']),
    'Sibiu': set(['Arad','Rimnicu Vilcea','Fagaras','Oradea']),
    'Arad': set(['Timisoara','Zerind','Sibiu']),
    'Timisoara': set(['Lugoj']),
    'Lugoj': set(['Mehadia']),
    'Mehadia': set(['Drobeta']),
    'Drobeta': set(['Craiova']),
    'Rimnicu Vilcea': set(['Craiova','Pitesti','Sibiu']),
    'Craiova': set(['Drobeta','Rimnicu Vilcea']),
    'Fagaras': set(['Bucharest','Sibiu']),
    'Pitesti': set(['Bucharest','Rimnicu Vilcea']),
    'Bucharest': set(['Giurgiu','Urziceni','Pitesti','Fagaras']),
    'Giurgiu': set(['Bucharest']),
    'Urziceni': set(['Hirsova','Vaslui','Bucharest']),
    'Hirsova': set(['Eforia','Urziceni']),
    'Eforia': set(['Hirsova']),
    'Vaslui': set(['Iasi','Urziceni']),
    'Iasi': set(['Neamt','Vaslui']),
    'Neamt': set(['Iasi'])}

def bfs(graph, start, end):
    queue = [(start, [start])]
    while queue:
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):
            if next == end:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                queue.append((next, path + [next]))        

def dfs(graph, start, goal):
    queue = []
    queue.append([start])
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path[-1]
        if node == end:
            return path
        for adjacent in graph.get(node,[]):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(adjacent)
            queue.append(new_path)

print('bfs')
bfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt')
print('dfs')
dfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt')
```

I keep getting this error when I run the algorithm:

```
 ---> 1 class GraphTree:
      2 
      3     graph = {
      4         'Oradea': set(['Zerind','Sibiu']),
      5         'Zerind': set(['Arad','Oradea']),
```

Another one at:
     49     bfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt')
     50     print('dfs')
 --> 51     dfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt')

And lastly:

```
 39             path = queue.pop(0)
 40             node = path[-1]
```

--> 41             if node == end:
     42                 return path
     43             for adjacent in graph.get(node,[]):

> NameError: name 'end' is not defined

The algorithm seems logically correct with the conditions and declaration ok.
Why is this search algorithm not working?

> The algorithm should be able to navigate the map going from one city to the other and returning the path using both breadth first (bfs) and depth first (dfs) searches.

Comment: In `if node == end:` where is end defined in this method?

Comment: Please provide full error message (as given by the compiler), with relevant line numbers and so on. That will make it easier for StackOverflow users to help you. Also, in some cases inspecting that line on your own will help you realize the problem immediately.

Comment: You used the name `goal` instead of `end` in `dfs()` parameter, but still try to `if node == end:`.

Comment: To piggy back on @ChristianNeverdal check the line above the error line as well, the python compiler can be weird with line numbers at times

Comment: Probably need to fix your spacing as well, something up there isn't lined up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had

```
bfs(graph, start, end)
```

and

```
dfs(graph, start, goal)
                  ^^^^
```

Some other notes to your code:

- You're not printing out the result of your searches, but it looks like you were intending to do that.
- You wrapped in all in a class, but you didn't do anything else in your code that actually required that.

With all of this in mind, here is another version:

```
graph = {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    'Oradea': set(['Zerind','Sibiu']),                                                                                                                                                                             
    'Zerind': set(['Arad','Oradea']),                                                                                                                                                                              
    'Sibiu': set(['Arad','Rimnicu Vilcea','Fagaras','Oradea']),                                                                                                                                                    
    'Arad': set(['Timisoara','Zerind','Sibiu']),                                                                                                                                                                   
    'Timisoara': set(['Lugoj']),                                                                                                                                                                                   
    'Lugoj': set(['Mehadia']),                                                                                                                                                                                     
    'Mehadia': set(['Drobeta']),                                                                                                                                                                                   
    'Drobeta': set(['Craiova']),                                                                                                                                                                                   
    'Rimnicu Vilcea': set(['Craiova','Pitesti','Sibiu']),                                                                                                                                                          
    'Craiova': set(['Drobeta','Rimnicu Vilcea']),                                                                                                                                                                  
    'Fagaras': set(['Bucharest','Sibiu']),                                                                                                                                                                         
    'Pitesti': set(['Bucharest','Rimnicu Vilcea']),                                                                                                                                                                
    'Bucharest': set(['Giurgiu','Urziceni','Pitesti','Fagaras']),                                                                                                                                                  
    'Giurgiu': set(['Bucharest']),                                                                                                                                                                                 
    'Urziceni': set(['Hirsova','Vaslui','Bucharest']),                                                                                                                                                             
    'Hirsova': set(['Eforia','Urziceni']),                                                                                                                                                                         
    'Eforia': set(['Hirsova']),                                                                                                                                                                                    
    'Vaslui': set(['Iasi','Urziceni']),                                                                                                                                                                            
    'Iasi': set(['Neamt','Vaslui']),                                                                                                                                                                               
    'Neamt': set(['Iasi'])}                                                                                                                                                                                        

def bfs(graph, start, end):                                                                                                                                                                                        
    queue = [(start, [start])]                                                                                                                                                                                     
    while queue:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        (vertex, path) = queue.pop(0)                                                                                                                                                                              
        for next in graph[vertex] - set(path):                                                                                                                                                                     
            if next == end:                                                                                                                                                                                        
                yield path + [next]                                                                                                                                                                                
            else:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                queue.append((next, path + [next]))                                                                                                                                                                

def dfs(graph, start, end):                                                                                                                                                                                        
    queue = []                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    queue.append([start])                                                                                                                                                                                          
    while queue:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        path = queue.pop(0)                                                                                                                                                                                        
        node = path[-1]                                                                                                                                                                                            
        if node == end:                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return path                                                                                                                                                                                            
        for adjacent in graph.get(node,[]):                                                                                                                                                                        
            new_path = list(path)                                                                                                                                                                                  
            new_path.append(adjacent)                                                                                                                                                                              
            queue.append(new_path)                                                                                                                                                                                 

print('bfs')                                                                                                                                                                                                       
print(list(bfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt')))                                                                                                                                                                         
print('dfs')                                                                                                                                                                                                       
print(dfs(graph, 'Oradea', 'Neamt'))
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
bfs
[['Oradea', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Sibiu', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Pitesti', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Sibiu', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Pitesti', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Timisoara', 'Lugoj', 'Mehadia', 'Drobeta', 'Craiova', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Pitesti', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Sibiu', 'Arad', 'Timisoara', 'Lugoj', 'Mehadia', 'Drobeta', 'Craiova', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Pitesti', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt'], ['Oradea', 'Zerind', 'Arad', 'Timisoara', 'Lugoj', 'Mehadia', 'Drobeta', 'Craiova', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt']]
dfs
['Oradea', 'Sibiu', 'Fagaras', 'Bucharest', 'Urziceni', 'Vaslui', 'Iasi', 'Neamt']
```

Comment: ok thank you... it works... just need to edit my method because it prints all nodes

Comment: @ThabisoMotswagole: I have added the output I got when I ran the example. What is your specific question? Try to figure out what _really_ happens in the code. Clean it up. Run it on paper.

Comment: I will do that thank you